# Json file content version variable value Increment by 0.0.1

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, json.net, version

Before I do a release of my package and tag it, I would like to update the manifest.json file version **Patch** value to reflect the new version of the package every time I trigger it.

Json file:

```
{
"version":  "0.0.0",
"timeStamp":  "2022-02-14T09:41:34+00:00",
"packages":  [
                 {
                     "name":  "data-service",
                     "type":  "docker-image",
                     "version":  "REL-1.0.5"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "application-service",
                     "type":  "docker-image",
                     "version":  "REL-1.0.6"
                 },
             ]
 }
```

So here I am trying to increment by reading the content of the Json file from Powershell:

```
version = (Get-Content manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json).version
```

Value for the variable "version" in the Json file is 0.0.0
But My question is - how to increase the only patch value? E.g. I need to have 0.0.1 output values after transform automatically in the manifest.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`[version]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version) to parse the existing version, then increment the build number:

```
$data = Get-Content manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# extract and increment version build number
$existingVersion = $data.version -as [version]
$nextVersion = [version]::new($existingVersion.Major, $existingVersion.Minor, $existingVersion.Build + 1)

# update original data
$data.version = "$nextVersion"

# write back to disk
$data |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content updated-manifest.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but one small doubt here, for the next build the same manifest file will get updated with the new value right? I mean the file name manifest.json file will not get renamed or change its name right. Because this manifest.json file will be used as a parameter for the build.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Why are you asking me? If you want to overwrite the same file, change `updated-manifest.json` to `manifest.json` (or whichever the file name is)